# Issue with src path

Tags: javascript, jquery, src

im having an issue with this piece of code not reading the correct path or something.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/cmarkercaller.js"></script> <!--Citymarker Caller-->
<script type="text/javascript">
```

my "index.html" is in the same folder as my "scripts" folder. 
Much Thanks for any advice / assistance!!

Comment: Try `./scripts/cmarkercaller.js`

Comment: `src="scripts/cmarkercaller.js`

Comment: maybe you have an extra "/" in the start of the path in the second script ..... if u have them in the same folder as u say.

Answer (score 2):

There is a path reference error with the second script. It should be either:

```
<script src="scripts/cmarkercaller.js"></script> <!--Citymarker Caller-->
```

or

```
<script src="./scripts/cmarkercaller.js"></script> <!--Citymarker Caller-->
```

depending on where `cmarkercaller.js` is located. You should keep the following in mind:

`/` means the root of the current drive;

`./` means the current directory;

`../` means the parent of the current directory.